# Why would a Burmese native prefer "alight from a bus" over "get off a bus"?

Tags: writing-style, esl

I recently read a script written in English by a Burmese native and it struck me as odd that they always used the phrase "**they alighted from a bus**" instead of the ordinary "**they got off a bus**".

I'm curious if there's a reason for it related to the fact that the author is Burmese.

Could it have to do with how English is taught in Burma or how you say it in Burmese? What could be the reason for this choice of words?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139352/discussion-on-question-by-eltomito-why-would-a-burmese-native-prefer-alight-fro).

Answer (score 3):

> I'm curious as to whether there's a reason for it related to the fact that the author is Burmese.

His being Burmese is only marginally relevant. Burma (now Myanmar) abandoned English as an official language in 1964. English is taught only as a foreign language.

A lot of the teaching and teaching material currently in such places reflects back on days when the British were influential*.

As we look at how this fellow learned his English, we can surmise that he learned it from people who were taught by people who learned their English c. 1920.

In 1920, the English that was taught was middle-class RP and "alight" was perfectly normal... it is now dated and formal.

*This fossilisation of English is not uncommon in poorer areas but fortunately, with the internet and social media, it is becoming less so as Current Modern English receives more exposure.

Comment: 'Debus' is a one-word synonym for 'alight from a/the bus' used in the British military but sometimes considered slang [[ODE](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA451&lpg=PA451&dq=%22unload+(personnel+or+stores)+from+a+vehicle%22&source=bl&ots=T-iwewlFxO&sig=ACfU3U26J6gi2P4xwPgI_6y6hWiueikGqQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyxMepnab6AhWSXsAKHacdDHYQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=%22unload%20(personnel%20or%20stores)%20from%20a%20vehicle%22&f=false)]. Slang or not, it would sound silly in everyday English.

Comment: I've been trying to find the "smoking gun" that would prove this theory and I'm searching the internet for a Myanmar English textbook that has "alight" in it but no success so far. There's a lot of them on learnbig.net and scribd.com but they are scanned images, so you can't search them with ctrl+f. I browsed about 7 of them already but found no mention of anyone getting off or alighting from anything yet.

Comment: @eltomito ... *I'm searching the internet for a Myanmar English textbook that has "alight" in it but no success so far.* Yes... well, good luck with that. How many Myanmar English textbooks printed pre-1980 do you think there are on the internet? ;) Others here will confirm (from questions asked) that old-fashioned English textbooks are quite common in poorer countries, particularly in rural areas and deprived urban areas, where students are lucky to get a textbook at all.

Comment: @Greybeard You may be right. Still, I'd like to see some kind of evidence or hear from someone who has actually seen a Myanmar textbook that has "alight" in it or heard that from people there.

Answer (score -3):

It seems to me that this is simply due to the peculiarity of their language. It's like the Norwegians have 40 different words describing different aggregate states of snow. Likewise, they do not get off the bus but alighted from the bus.

Comment: So the [Great  Eskimo Snow Hoax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eskimo_words_for_snow) has now moved to Norwegian has it? But even if it were real, it would not really be relevant here. Nonetheless, your point is valid: it is simply a different choice among the possible words and phrases for the activity. It is not a "peculiarity" - except perhaps, that as in India and Pakistan, the English often feels old-fashioned to British (and presumably even more) American readers.

Comment: The term peculiarity is a judgment, if not a slur. But the question is about English, not Burmese directly.

Comment: @YosefBaskin That doesn't seem in any way reasonable to me. *Peculiarity* in this sense means 'specific individual quality' not 'strangeness'. The connotations of your comment are far from pleasant, and it seems to me the comment itself is extremely ill-founded. See definition 2: [***something that is typical of one person, group, or thing***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/peculiarity) in the Cambridge Dictionary. Please be more careful. (and delete your comment)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I have great respect for your contributions, and we can still disagree. I do not feel hinting that a slur is a slur is unreasonable, unpleasant, ill-founded, or careless. I can always delete my original comment.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I do not understand why you think it is a slur?

Comment: Because the rich have eccentricity and the poor, peculiarity. Moreover, if the answer were attributing mother-tongue influence, that point *would* have value. As written, where's the connection between Burmese peculiarities and 'alighted', which is quaint?